# FALLO - Apliación desplegada en la ruta de contexto [/ecommerce], pero el contexto no pudo arrancar

Tags: java, bootstrap, jsp, java-ee

Estoy trabajando una aplicación web con jsp (java), servidor Tomcat 9 pero me genera el error que aparece en la imagen.

FALLO - Apliación desplegada en la ruta de contexto [/ecommerce], pero el contexto no pudo arrancar.

Lo único que modifoqué fue el index para embeber el llamado a un método que me  despliega unas categorias el index.jsp con unas categorias, antes de eso funcionaba bien:

---

### carpeta WEB-INF ---> archivo ---> web.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<web-app version="3.1" xmlns="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_3_1.xsd">
<servlet>
    <servlet-name>Home</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>view.Home</servlet-class>
</servlet>
<servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>Home</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>home</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>
<session-config>
    <session-timeout>
        30
    </session-timeout>
</session-config>
<error-page>
    <location>/404.html</location>
</error-page>
```

---

### index.jsp

<% response.sendRedirect("home");

---

### Source Packages/view/Home.java

```
package view;

import java.io.IOException;
import javax.servlet.ServletException;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletResponse;
```

/**

```
public class Home extends HttpServlet {

    /**
    * Processes requests for both HTTP <code>GET</code> and    <code>POST</code>
    * methods.
    *
    * @param request servlet request
    * @param response servlet response
    * @throws ServletException if a servlet-specific error occurs
    * @throws IOException if an I/O error occurs
   */
     protected void processRequest(HttpServletRequest request,    HttpServletResponse response)
           throws ServletException, IOException {
          response.setContentType("text/html;charset=UTF-8");
       request.getRequestDispatcher("WEB-INF/index.jsp").forward(request,  response);
}

   // <editor-fold defaultstate="collapsed" desc="HttpServlet methods. Click on the + sign on the left to edit the code.">
/** 
 * Handles the HTTP <code>GET</code> method.
 *
 * @param request servlet request
 * @param response servlet response
 * @throws ServletException if a servlet-specific error occurs
 * @throws IOException if an I/O error occurs
 */
   @Override
    protected void doGet(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response)
            throws ServletException, IOException {
        processRequest(request, response);
    }

/**
 * Handles the HTTP <code>POST</code> method.
 *
 * @param request servlet request
 * @param response servlet response
 * @throws ServletException if a servlet-specific error occurs
 * @throws IOException if an I/O error occurs
 */
 @Override
    protected void doPost(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse   response)
            throws ServletException, IOException {
         processRequest(request, response);
    }

/**
 * Returns a short description of the servlet.
 *
 * @return a String containing servlet description
 */
  @Override
   public String getServletInfo() {
      return "Short description";
   }// </editor-fold>
```

}

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Anexo enlace a repositorio: https://github.com/hgarciaospina/EcommerceJEE.git

Comment: Hola. Te está diciendo que el contexto no pudo arrancar. Eso significa que hay algún problema de falta de dependencias o que algo del código que se ejecuta al arrancar la aplicación está fallando. Por favor, revisa bien los logs de Tomcat y busca el error exacto que se está produciendo

Comment: Hazle caso al mensaje y revisa el server log

Answer (score 0):

Normalmente, el mensaje se presenta porque hay algún error en las dependencias.

Es posible que falte alguna dependencia en algún servidor; por ejemplo, si fuera un error por parte del servidor *tomcat*, es porque hace falta la dependencia del mismo y es necesario agregarla al archivo `pom`.

```
<!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.apache.tomcat/tomcat -->
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.apache.tomcat</groupId>
    <artifactId>tomcat</artifactId>
    <version>9.0.0.M1</version>
    <type>pom</type>
</dependency>
```

Answer (score 0):

Importante que valides que el Netbeans lo arranques con administrador, ya con esto eliminas el error que no lo puede implementar.

Comment: Esto no provee una respuesta a la pregunta.  En cuanto tengas suficiente [reputación](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation) podrás [comentar en cualquier publicación](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment). Es mejor [dar respuestas que no requieran clarificación de la persona que hizo la pregunta](https://es.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/586/). - [Desde revisión](/review/late-answers/321848)

Answer (score 0):

Me paso algo parecido con (AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:287), pero solo modifique archivos jsp, elimine archivos generados con netbeans para crear un nuevo proyecto de aplicación web Java a partir de un proyecto de aplicación web existente.

Comment: Tal y como está redactada, tu respuesta no es clara. Por favor, pulsa en [edit] para añadir detalles adicionales que ayuden a los demás a entender cómo esto responde a la pregunta formulada. Puedes encontrar más información sobre cómo escribir buenas respuestas [en el centro de ayuda](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: Esto realmente no responde a la pregunta. Si tienes una pregunta diferente, la puedes formular haciendo clic en [Formular una pregunta](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/ask). También puedes [ofrecer una recompensa](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/set-bounties) para atraer más atención a esta pregunta cuando tengas suficiente [reputación](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation). - [Desde revisión](/review/late-answers/362488)

Answer (score 0):

En el tag pattern del archivo web.xml le falta el "/"

```
<servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>Home</servlet-name>
    **<url-pattern>/home</url-pattern>**
</servlet-mapping>
```

Esto también pasa cuando en el nombre de un servlet se omite el "/"
lo correcto es **@WebServlet("/nombre_servlet")**.

Answer (score 0):

Me ocurrió lo mismo y, revisando el código, algunos de los urlPatterns (los que agregé recientemente) del servlet no iniciaban con las barras invertidas "/"

```
    -- Código anterior
@WebServlet(name = "SvEmpleado", urlPatterns = {"/SvEmpleado", "/mainEmpleado", "/viewcreateE", "viewupdateE", "viewdeleteE"})

    -- Código modificado
@WebServlet(name = "SvEmpleado", urlPatterns = {"/SvEmpleado", "/mainEmpleado", "/viewcreateE", "/viewupdateE", "/viewdeleteE"})
```

Luego de arreglar el error, se ejecutó el archivo index sin problemas.

En resumen, puede que salga el mensaje de fallo por errores de código dentro del servlet.

Answer (score -1):

Este error es frecuente, lo he arreglado guardando todos los cambios, reiniciando el servidor(tomcat/glassfish), cerrando y volviendo a abrir la IDE.

Algunas veces he borrado .m2 y luego vuelvo a bajar las dependencias.

Y listo.